# How to find if a file has been created on the same machine or not?

Tags: c#, file, filesystems, ntfs

I'm working with a file in my c# application which I need to check the legitimacy of that every time I access it. Is there any way to find if the file came from another computer or has been crated on the same machine?
I think there is a kind of flag or else that indicates the file came from another PC, like the following screenshot:

[image]

Comment: How is the file created? An alternative could be cryptographically signing the file so verify it's origin.

Comment: How can "other machine" can created the file? I think, OS only keep tracking it while created in its own machine. Maybe you can track created user OR the owner, but not the machine CMIIW. And while it's not supported by OS, maybe you can create your own custom application to solve your problem. Maybe filewatcher is a good solution to match your problem. You can track and match when is the last access and last modified of that file.

Comment: I think there is something in the file system that shows this. Please look at [this screenshot](http://i60.tinypic.com/30xdav7.jpg)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This information is stored in `Zone.Identifier` NTFS [Alternate Data Stream](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS#Alternate_data_streams_.28ADS.29). You can access Alternate Data Streams very much like normal file data (which itself is also a stream - an *unnamed data stream*):

- In Command Prompt you have to append the name of the stream, prefixed by `:` to the file path:

  `more < some_file.exe:Zone.Identifier`
- In Powershell it goes like this:

  `Get-Content -Path some_file.exe -Stream Zone.Identifier`

In both cases, if the file is marked as downloaded from external location it outputs:

```
[ZoneTransfer]
ZoneId=3
```

Possible valid values of `ZoneId` and their meanings are ([from blog entry about ADS](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askcore/archive/2013/03/24/alternate-data-streams-in-ntfs.aspx)):

```
0 My Computer
1 Local Intranet Zone 
2 Trusted sites Zone 
3 Internet Zone 
4 Restricted Sites Zone
```

Unfortunately there is no CLR class that provides support (at least none that I know of) for ADS. You can consider using [these classes](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2670/Accessing-alternative-data-streams-of-files-on-an) or command line tool [Streams](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897440.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) provided my Microsoft for accessing them.

**EDIT:**
Of course you can easily invoke Powershell commands from C#, but that would force users of your application to have at least Powershell 2.0 and probably .NET 4.0 or higher (not sure about the latter):

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (PowerShell powerShellInstance = PowerShell.Create())
        {
            powerShellInstance.AddCommand("Get-Content");
            powerShellInstance.AddParameter("-Path", @"C:\Path\To\File.exe");
            powerShellInstance.AddParameter("-Stream", "Zone.Identifier");

            Collection<PSObject> output = powerShellInstance.Invoke();

            foreach (PSObject obj in output)
            {
                if (obj != null && obj.ToString().StartsWith("ZoneId"))                        
                    Console.WriteLine(obj);                 
            }
        }
    }
```